# Как объяснить тире в этом сложном предложении?

Tags: тире, сложное-предложение, двоеточие

Из художественной **литературы:**

В тот раз, что она к нам заехала, у нас была Зоя. Бальзаковская баронесса де Нусинген и диккенсовская крошка Доррит. Лика сразу у нее спросила, где заварочный чайник, потому что принесла коробку Липтона и хочет свежего крепкого чаю, та сказала: давайте я сама. *Расстались, как подруги, Лика это умела: **она дающая, другой принимающий —** в дверях стянула с шеи шифоновый платок, накинула на Зою, поцеловала.* Вечером Зоя позвонила: дайте мне ее телефон, хочу тоже сделать подарок. Жостовский поднос — как вам кажется? я слышала, иностранцы это любят. Через несколько дней где-то они встретились, и назавтра Зоя мне сказала: с ней лучше дружить; она мне нравится, я бы с ней вообще могла дружить, но сверх того это и безопасней.

**Какой знак** и почему нужно считать **основным** (более сильным) знаком — двоеточие или тире?

**Примечание.** Основной знак обозначает границу между двумя частями сложной конструкции (**по смыслу и по интонации)**.

**Дополнительно**: почему обособлен оборот с союзом ***КАК***?

Comment: Sharon, я не очень понимаю, что вы понимаете под основным знаком. Двоеточие ( если о нем идет речь, как вы верно заметили, обозначает границу между двумя частями сложной конструкции. Тире присоединительное. Обособлен сравнительный оборот. Хотя есть  обстоятельственное значение. Впрочем, все зависит от контекста.

Comment: Контекста для сравнительного оборота достаточно, чтобы определиться с обособлением. В первой части БСП, бессоюзная связь, запятых НЕ МНОГО ЛИ?  //  Так граница по двоеточию? А читать как будете присоединительную конструкцию? Интонационное предупреждение  по двоеточию, а потом ну очень РАСПРОСТРАНЕННАЯ вторая часть. Читаем скороговоркой? НЕ ОЧЕНЬ РАЗУМНО поставлены знаки — вот что я имею в виду.

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю такой вариант:

*Расстались, как подруги, Лика это умела, — **она дающая, другой принимающий,** — в дверях стянула с шеи шифоновый платок, накинула на Зою, поцеловала.*

Вставка, вторая запятая **перенесенная**, первая для **симметрии.** Вставка интонационно **не смещена** в какую-либо сторону.

**Пояснение**

**Почему именно так?**

1. Это предложение делится **не на две, а на три** части по всем показателям: **по семантике, по объему, по интонации.** В то же время его необходимо разделить на два блока **по [правилу ПАС](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=136#pp136).**
2. Тогда среднюю часть надо оформить **как вставку,** что соответствует **семантике и грамматике** предложения: это **дополнительное** сообщение, выделяющееся из общей **структуры.**

Answer (score 1):

*Расстались, как подруги (Лика это умела: она дающая, другой принимающий), — в дверях стянула с шеи шифоновый платок, накинула на Зою, поцеловала.*

Логичным, считаю, было бы отделить суждение от повествования. О двоеточии: оно в условиях частокола наших стоек и штрихов визуально не срабатывает как знак паузы, да и его *момент отмены* определить бывает трудно. И ещё: это не самое главное, но «принимающего» заменил бы на «принимающую».

Comment: Спасибо за внимание к вопросу и за ответ. В вашем варианте имя "Лика" уходит из главной части, а это не совсем хорошо. Я добавила КОНТЕКСТ.  Не стала бы менять "принимающий", здесь скорее обобщение.  Двоеточие сильный знак и  обычно ставится на границе двух блоков.  Все-таки надо ориентироваться на Лопатина (универсальный метод).

Answer (score 1):

• Трудно судить, *как* рассуждал известный автор этого предложения ([Анатолий Найман](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD,_%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)) и *как* он расставлял акценты...
Но *мне* хочется "вынести" фразу "она дающая, другой принимающий" в конец предложения и оформить ее как вставку.

Вот так:
*Расстались, как подруги, Лика это умела: в дверях стянула с шеи шифоновый платок, накинула на Зою, поцеловала — она дающая, другой принимающий.*
Или так:
*...накинула на Зою, поцеловала (она — дающая, другой — принимающий).*

• Думаю, что постановка запятой перед сравнительным оборотом вполне оправданна.

*Они расстались, **как подруги,** мина была подложена незаметно, а Алене было о чем подумать* (Ян Отченашек. Хромой Орфей).

P. S. *Я слышала, иностранцы это любят* (думаю, что с прописной буквы).

Comment: Изящный вопрос. Спасибо.

Comment: Спасибо за варианты, мне тоже думается, что это вставка. Но еще мне хочется избавиться от двоеточия. Почему?  А это у меня идея фикс о блоках, которую никто принимать во внимание не хочет, хотя это ведь Лопатин! Предложение должно делиться на два блока основным знаком, в том числе интонационно.  И вот здесь это деление получается неравноценным по объему. Получается, что вторая часть должна быть связанным фрагментом. Мы даже не можем эту вставку прочитать как вставку, ее приходится "приклеивать" к основной части.

Comment: Поэтому мне хочется расположить ее посередине, на нейтральной полосе.  (Не знаю, понятно ли я говорю. )  Как вы к этому относитесь?

Comment: Почему не отвечаешь мне, Рим? Надоел уже этот сайт хуже горькой редьки! Спрашиваешь, а тебе не отвечают.

Comment: Да вот она я, Артём! Не все сообщения почему-то доходят. Провинилась в чем-то? Я "вся внимание".

Comment: Ура! Странно, я писал с собачкой! Спросил тебя, как правильно, в вопросе про село в одного человека.

Comment: Да, интереснейший вопрос! Помню. ***Вопросище***, можно сказать. Я его, конечно, отметила. И поразмышляла. И даже много-много порылась-покопалась. Нашла кой-что... Ну не филолог я, Артём! Где же ж мне?.. Погодь маленько — может, созрею. Очень уж не хочется на профессиональные пинки нарываться. P. S. И-эх! Умеешь ты достать. Подумаю...

Comment: Кого я чем достал?! Что ещё за поворот такой?

Comment: Не поняла, какой такой поворот, Артём? Глагол "достать" — многозначный, хороший. Я имела в виду значение *раздобыть, получить* (то есть добиться желаемого, настоять). Никаких других смыслов я не подразумевала.

Comment: Ничего себе, даже не думал, что мог быть хороший смысл! Очень рад!))